# Google Sheets - Sum of hours on table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table that looks like this at work (it's an example, not a real table):

[image]

And the second table at the bottom, we sum manually using SUM formula and selecting the range by hand to check how many hours there are in each story. I'd like to know if there is a way to create a formula that automatically detects the sum range of story tasks and calculates it:

[image]

Hope it's clear what I need because in this example, there are 2 stories, and each story has an exact 3 tasks, but in the real world, each story has different numbers of the task. We never put how many hours we'll need in the storyline, just on task lines.

Comment: To make this dynamic you should look into Google Script and write a plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete B11 and B12 and paste this formula into B11 cell and drag down:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(A11, B:B, 0)+1, 4, 4)&":"&
      ADDRESS(IFERROR(MATCH(A12, B:B, 0)-1, ROW()-3), 4, 4)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I edited my question, it was not clear, I want to try to find the sum range automatically

Answer (score 1):

In cell B11, type this: =SUM(D3:D5). This is the sum for Story 1.
In cell B12, type this: =SUM(D7:D9). This is the sum for Story 2.

The function will add all of the values in the range you give it. So D3:D5 means D3, D4 and D5.

Comment: That's what we do today, what I'm looking for is if there is a way of google sheets to figure out this sum range automatically :)